# How to fill an area with filled flowerpots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was working on a mob-proof house and came upon the knowledge of ferns in a flowerpot give damage to mobs, and wanted to cover a large area, that would take hours by hand. I tried using the command:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 flower_pot 11
```

I used 11 because minecraft wiki says that that is the variation id.
This filled the area I wanted, but left all the pots empty. I tried toying with the command, and could not find any articles online about it. I found this one article (after several minutes of hair pulling) and it only explained how to do this one block at a time, and would reduce maybe 20 minutes. Does anyone have any clue how to make this happen with the /fill command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will do it:

```
/fill X1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 flower_pot 0 destroy {Item:31,Data:2}
```

The curly brackets define the item in the pot.  31/2 is a fern.

[Here is a list of item ID's I used to identify.](http://minecraft-ids.grahamedgecombe.com/) You can also toggle on advanced tooltips by pressing F3 and H while playing to view the data of items in your inventory.

Comment: The Minecraft Wiki also has a list of IDs.